# How add the button dynamicaly

Tags: javascript

i want to add the button in each images.
but the below javascript function was not working

```
function imagesSelected(myFiles) {
      for (var i = 0, f; f = myFiles[i]; i++) {
        var imageReader = new FileReader();
        imageReader.onload = (function(aFile) 
       {
          return function(e) {
            var span = document.createElement('span');

            span.innerHTML = [
                "<p><b>" + aFile.name + "</b></p><br>"+'<img class="images" src="', e.target.result,'" title="', aFile.name, '" />'+"<strong>" + aFile.name + "</strong><INPUT type="button" value="Add"/>"].join('');

            document.getElementById('thumbs').insertBefore(span, null);
          };
        })(f);
        imageReader.readAsDataURL(f);
      }
}
```

Comment: Syntax error - aFile.name + "</strong><INPUT type="button" value="Add"/>" it needs to be aFile.name + "</strong><INPUT type='button' value='Add'/>" , because you are escaping the string when you are using the " twice.

Comment: Its working now.thank you

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem in your for loop. You have to pass a start value, a stop condition and an incrementer. Try this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < myFiles.length; i++) {
    var f = myFiles[i];
    ...
}
```

Check the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for).